# Error while attempting to create a button within a table

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to create a button within a table that passes its particular field data into a javascript function upon it being clicked, however when I press the 2nd button I get a "Uncaught syntax error: missing ) after argument list", can anyone see anything wrong with the code?

```
echo '<tr>
                  <td scope="row">' . $row["Type"]. '</td>
                  <td><img src='.$row['Image'].' height="100" width="100"></td>
                  <td> '.$row["Price"] .'</td>
                  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id = "buybtn" onclick="foodChosen('.$row["Type"].','.$row["Price"].')">Buy</button></td>
     </tr>';
}
```

Comment: The error gets called on the "<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id = "buybtn" onclick="foodChosen('.$row["Type"].','.$row["Price"].')">Buy</button></td>" line

Comment: Is `$row["Type"]` a string?  If so, it needs to be quoted when passed to the function

Comment: @PatrickQ That worked to get rid of that issue but now I'm getting an unexpected end of input error at the same location

Comment: @GeorgeSmith You'll need to update your question to show what code you're using now (and also include the exact new error message in the update).

Answer (score 0):

Drop out of PHP before outputting that block of code and use a consistent quoting style.

```
?>
<tr>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $row['Type']; ?></td>
    <td><img src="<?php echo $row['Image']; ?>" height="100" width="100"></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Price']; ?></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="buybtn" onclick="foodChosen('<?php echo $row['Type'] . ',' . $row["Price"]; ?>')">Buy</button></td>
</tr>
```